# share current url in webview from toolbar menu

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-webview

I am stuck at the last phase of my project. I am developing a android webview app in which user can share the current loaded page in there social apps. My share button is in the top at the toolbar. Currently I am able to share the loaded url through the share button but when I jump to a new page and press share button, still initial loaded url is shared. **Here I need to share the current url from the toolbar menu.**

Please help

Following is my code

```
package com.newsflashjharkhand.newflash;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewsFlash extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar superProgressBar;
    ImageView superImageView;
    WebView superWebView;

    String mUrl = "";
    private String mTitle = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_flash);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbaar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        superProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.newsprogressbar);
        superImageView  = findViewById(R.id.newsimage);
        superWebView = findViewById(R.id.newswebview);

        superProgressBar.setMax(100);
        superWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        superWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        superWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                mUrl = view.getUrl();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mTitle = view.getTitle();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
        superWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                superProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.btn_share:
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = mUrl;

                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Using"));
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (superWebView.canGoBack()) {
            superWebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewsFlash.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) with your webview like below:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(context);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.." + url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.. finish" + url);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("when you click on any interlink on webview that time you got url :-" + url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
```

You can get current loaded url from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` .

Comment: Thanks but it did not help

Comment: @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                mUrl = view.getUrl();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

Comment: @Tariq, shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method actually provides what url is being loading internally. You should first implement and check result. Thankyou

Comment: Thanks. Will try and let you know soon